# Jump to corresponding html tag in vim

Tags: vim

I am editing an `html` file in `vim`.

How do I jump to a corresponding tag? So, from `<b>`, go to `</b>`, etc.

`%` takes me to the corresponding closing element i.e. from `<` to `>` or from `(` to `)` etc.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/501001/2072269. Also, if you're interested in Vim, checkout [vi.se].

Comment: [Using % in languages without curly braces](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/126/51), [How to jump between matching HTML/XML tags?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/780/51)

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways of doing it. One is a motion, the solution I am using. `vat` will select the whole area between two matching tags. Then `o` will take you to the beginning or end.

The other option is a plugin. matchit is a plugin that will do the same with fewer keystrokes.